# Find 2D plane in the center of nonlinear 3D object

Tags: matrices, 3d, surfaces, plane-geometry

I'm building a segmentation algorithm. I'm segmenting pieces of paper in a book that have been slightly crumpled. Imagine taking a piece of paper, crumpling it into a ball, and then trying to straighten it back out.

The piece of paper is an actually 3D object, but I want to segment a 2D plane running through the geometrical center of the 3D object. Is this a center of mass problem?

I have a 3D matrix of binary values -- 1 being on the piece of paper, and 0 not on the piece of paper.

What kind of algorithm can I run to find the 2D plane?

Comment: What is the "center" of the 3D object? Is that the center of mass? Or the plane you are looking for should have some other property?

Comment: @Aretino thank you for the clarification. I mean the geometrical center

Comment: "Geometrical center" is meaningless, in general.

Comment: If what you need is the center of mass, then it is very easy to compute it. But I suppose you already know that.

Comment: @Aretino perhaps you can explain how the center of mass would work?I mean it is uniform density, so I suppose center of mass would work

Comment: Would work for what? From your question I only unterstand that you need a plane passing through the ill-defined center of an object. But what do you want to do with that plane?

Comment: @Aretino I will create a new 3D matrix with 1's in a single plane running through the 3D "page"

Comment: And then? What is the use of such a plane? There are infinite planes passing through the center of mass of a given shape.

Answer (score 1):

For volumes the "geometric center" usually refers to the *medial axis*; for algorithms to compute it see for instance [this paper](http://www.balintmiklos.com/scale-axis/algorithm_siggraph_2010.html#tab). However note that the medial axis of 3D volume can be topologically complex (consisting of sheets and curves glued together) and you will require significant post-processing to get anything resembling a developable surface from the medial axis of a page-shaped volume.

You're probably better off trying to fit a surface through the point cloud representing your page, rather than computing any kind of center. If you post a picture of the input mesh, I can give you more specific advice.